# usage of resources in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I don't want to specify hard coded test size values in my layout.xml, hence i am using the following specification :

```
android:layout_height="@integer/intervalViewHt"
```

and 
   @integer/intervalViewHt value is as follows:

```
<integer name="medium">15</integer>
```

Now, the while inflating android is creating a problem saying that it cannot inflate the view. I want to actually specify value in `dp` so the actual value should be like

```
android:layout_height="15dp"
```

Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are ["dimensions"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) rather than plain integers.

Declaration:

```
<dimen name="intervalViewHt">15dp</dimen>
```

Usage:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/intervalViewHt"
```

Have a look at the given link for more examples in the Android docs.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for text size across different devices.  It's java based, not xml.

```
tvOutput.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DP, getResource().getInteger(R.integer.medium));
```

I haven't tested the code so you might have to play with it.  I'm sure you could do something like.

```
button1.setHeight(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DP, getResource().getInteger(R.integer.medium));
```

Though again I haven't tried it and you may need something different then *TypedValue*

Answer (score -1):

What if you give it a String rather than an int. i.e in strings resource you have a string "15dp" that you reference

Comment: textSize and attributes similar need to be integers i.e. numbers, we can't specify string in their place.